# dollar-terminated strings

Tags: assembly, console, dos, nasm

In my assembly language class, our first assignment was to write a program to print out a simple dollar-terminated string in DOS.  It looked something like this:

```
BITS 32
    global _main

section .data
    msg db "Hello, world!", 13, 10, ’$’

section .text
_main:
mov ah, 9
mov edx, msg
int 21h
ret
```

As I understand it, the $ sign serves to terminate the sting like null does in C.  But what do I do if I want to put a dollar sign in the string (like I want to print out "it costs $30")?  This seems like a simple question, but my professor didn't know the answer and I don't seem to find it using a google search.

Comment: `BITS 32`??  How are you getting your DOS program to execute in 32-bit mode, but still be able to use `int 21h` DOS calls?  If the machine code actually executes in 16-bit mode, the 16-bit `mov r16, imm16` instruction that decodes is a different length than the 32-bit `mov r32, imm32` NASM emitted, so the high 2 bytes of the `msg` address would decode as an instruction.  (Possibly `00 00  add [bx+si], al`, using up those 2 bytes exactly, letting execution reach `int 21h`, so it's possible your code happened to work even in 16-bit mode)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use DOS's `0x09` service to display `$` signs, you'll need to use `0x02`. See [here](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah02).

Comment: It looks like 0x40 should work as well:  http://www.uv.tietgen.dk/staff/mlha/PC/Prog/asm/int/21/40.htm

Comment: Alternatively, you can use 0x40, but that requires you specify the number of bytes to write (i.e. it doesn't use delimited strings).

Comment: @Jason — Heh, beat me by one second. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Or make your own print_string to print a NULL-terminated string using the undocumented INT 29h (print character in AL).

```
; ds:si = address of string to print
print_string:
    lodsb                   ; load next character from ds:si
    or al, al               ; test for NULL-character
    jz .end_of_string       ; end of string encountered, return.
    int 29h                 ; print character in AL on screen
    jmp print_string        ; print next character
.end_of_string:
    ret                     ; return to callers cs:ip
```

(Assuming you are using NASM)

Comment: Note that if using INT 29h redirection of stdout won't work (e.g test.com > output.txt)

Comment: The preferred idiom is `test al,al` for setting FLAGS according to a register.  `or al,al` is slower (on modern x86), and was never better than `test` on historical x86.  [Test whether a register is zero with CMP reg,0 vs OR reg,reg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33724806).  Of course you can also tighten up the loop by putting the load and conditional branch at the bottom, and entering the loop with a `jmp` to the `lodsb`.  [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47783926)

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using the `write` service (`AH=0x40`):

- `AH=0x40`
- `BX` is the file handle; use the value 1 to write to the same device (such as the screen) as service `AH=9`
- `CX` is the number of bytes to be written; the data is not "terminated" (neither by NUL nor by `$`), so all values (from 0 to 255) can be written
- `DS:DX` points to the data (in your case: the string) to be written
  (Just like for service `AH=9`; If you use a 32-bit DOS extension: `EDX`, of course)

The service is actually intended for writing data to a file; however, it can also be used to write a "string" to the "output" by setting `BX` to 1.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to find the call that prints a single character.  You can print any character with that.  Break the string up and print "it costs ", then the '$',  and finally, "30".  More work, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **02 service** of INT 21H instead of **09 service**.

Here is the sample.

```
mov dl, '$'

mov ah,02

int 21h
```

Answer (score -2):

Um. You could write assembly that would taken into account for escaped `$`, e.g. `\$`?
But then your `\` becomes a special symbol too, and you need to use `\\` to print a `\`

Comment: `int 21h` / AH=9 is a DOS "system call".  You don't write the implementation of it, just calls to it.  It's the DOS equivalent of ISO C `puts` or `fputs(..., stdout)`, except it annoyingly uses `'$'` instead of `0` as a terminator.  See [Why did DOS use dollar-terminated strings?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/7638) on retrocomputing.  If you mean writing your own string-output function, then simply don't use `$` terminators in the first place.  Making it use `$` but in an incompatible way to DOS has near zero value.

Answer (score -5):

Try '$$', '\044' (octal) or '\x24' (hex)

Comment: The problem is not that the `$` cannot be specified in a string: Typing `db "This costs $100."` works absolutely well: It will "create" a string with a `$` in the middle. The problem is that in assembly language there is absolutely no possibility to find out if this is only one string or two strings (for example: `"This "` and `"costs $100."`). The function used by the OP uses the `$` to find the end of the string. `"$$"` won't work because the "next string" might begin with a `$`: The two strings `"Hello world."` and `"$100"` would be equal to: `"Hello world.$$100."`